# How do I filter column values for years 2019, 2020, and 2021 within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, filtering

The "REPAIR_YEAR" column in my dataframe consists of many different years (2018, 2019, etc).

Using pandas, I would like to define a new dataframe where all rows are filtered based on the years 2019, 2020, and 2021 from the REPAIR_YEAR column.

How do I do this?

Comment: try : `df[df['REPAIR_YEAR'].dt.year.isin([2019,2020,2021])]`

Comment: I'm receiving an error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

How do I manage this?  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: then convert your **'REPAIR_YEAR'** column to `datetime` dtype by `df['REPAIR_YEAR']=pd.to_datetime(df['REPAIR_YEAR'])` after that use the above method

Comment: What kind of values actually are in `REPAIR_YEAR`? Also: do you understand how to do *any kind* of filtering on a Dataframe? If not, what happened when you tried putting `pandas filter dataframe` into a search engine?

Comment: The values should be just 2018, 2019, 2020, and 2021.  After using the pd.to_datetime script, the results are placing the year at the end (below).  It looks like it thinks the year is 1970 when it should be years 2018-2021.
594   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020
595   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020
596   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020
597   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002019
598   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002020

Answer (score 1):

Considering the following dataframe

```
[In]: df = pd.DataFrame({"REPAIR_YEAR": [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022], "Letters": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c"]})
[Out]:
   REPAIR_YEAR Letters
0   2017       a
1   2018       a
2   2019       a
3   2020       a
4   2021       b
5   2022       c
```

Create a condition to filter the columns where `REPAIR_YEAR` is equal to 2019 or 2020 or 2021

```
condition = (df["REPAIR_YEAR"] == 2019) | (df["REPAIR_YEAR"] == 2020) | (df["REPAIR_YEAR"] == 2021)
```

Then apply the conditions to a new dataframe as follows

```
[In]: new_df = df[condition]
[Out]:
   REPAIR_YEAR Letters
0   2019       a
1   2020       a
2   2021       b
```